# Android как установить фото на телефон в хорошем качествe

Tags: android

```
WallpaperManager wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

InputStream ins = null;

ins = new URL(imglink).openStream();

wpm.setStream(ins);
```

этим кодам останавлеваю фоту но телефон но фото останавлеваица в плохом качесте .
как установить фото в хорошем качесте ?

imglink берет фото с интернета .

Comment: А ты посмотри в каком качестве оно скачивает с интернета и в каком разрешении оно его ставит :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, варианта три:

1. Фото изначально загружается в плохом качестве (выставьте его, как фон `Activity` и увидите его настоящее качество).
2. Фото растягивается на всю вертикальную длину (обычно, на главном экране телефона 3 экрана, которые перелистываются), а не на один экран.
3. Фото ставиться размером с `layout` файл `Activity`.

Comment: может вы знаете как можна получить фото  c picasaweb так штоб он подашол на установку к телефону ?

Comment: @DavidKern, к сожалению, нет. Тут задачу нужно разбить на два этапа: 1. Скачать фотографию в нужном разрешении (а это проблематично, так как у каждого телефона свое разрешение). 2. Установить фотографию. По очереди, думаю, Вы без проблем найдете ответы на вопросы, как это сделать.

Comment: спосибо :)))))))